# How can I bind a comma separated list in a URL to an array of objects?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a class named VerseRangeReference that has the properties Chapter, FirstVerse and LastVerse.

I have decorated it with a TypeConverterAttribute `[TypeConverter(typeof(VerseRangeReferenceConverter))]`

I have an action on a controller like this

`public Task<ViewResult> Verses(VerseRangeReference[] verses)`

But the value of `verses` is always a single element with the value `null`. Here is my type converter

```
public class VerseRangeReferenceConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

        if (value.GetType() == typeof(string))
        {
            string source = (string)value;
            return VerseRangeReference.ParseMultiple(source);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The result of `VerseRangeReference.ParseMultiple(source)` is a valid array of instances of VerseRange.

Comment: Note that you made a type converter for `VerseRangeReference`, not for `VerseRangeReference[]`. So you can convert a string into a single `VerseRangeReference` but not an array. You should probably convert into some kind of wrapper object instead that allows storing multiple values.

Comment: A TypeConverter only lets you specify the source type. There isn't a way to specify the return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to implement a custom model binder. If someone can think of a way to do this with a TypeConverter then I will accept that answer instead because model binders are more complicated.

```
public class VerseRangeReferenceArrayModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        string modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);
        if (valueProviderResult != ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            VerseRangeReference[] verseRangeReferences = VerseRangeReference.ParseMultiple(valueProviderResult.FirstValue);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(verseRangeReferences);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class VerseRangerReferenceArrayModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(VerseRangeReference[]))
            return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(VerseRangeReferenceArrayModelBinder));
        return null;
    }
}
```

This must be registered.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new VerseRangerReferenceArrayModelBinderProvider());
})
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a type converter to bind a comma separated string to a sequence of values. However, the type converter should convert from the string to the sequence directly. This means that the type converter should be configured for something like `IEnumerable<T>` or `T[]`. To simplify matters I will continue my explanation for `IEnumerable<int>` but if you want to use arrays instead you should just make sure that the type converter converts to an array instead of something that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

You can configure a type converter for `IEnumerable<int>` using `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes`:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(
    typeof(IEnumerable<int>),
    new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(EnumerableIntTypeConverter)));
```

This configures `EnumerableIntTypeConverter` as a type converter that can convert `IEnumerable<int>`.

This call has to be made when the process starts and in the case of ASP.NET Core this can conveniently be done in the `Startup.Configure` method.

Here is the `EnumerableIntTypeConverter` that converts the comma separated string of numbers to a list of ints:

```
internal class EnumerableIntTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    private const char Separator = ',';

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
        => sourceType == typeof(string);

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (!(value is string @string))
            throw new NotSupportedException($"{GetType().Name} cannot convert from {(value != null ? value.GetType().FullName : "(null)")}.");

        if (@string.Length == 0)
            return Enumerable.Empty<int>();

        var numbers = new List<int>();
        var start = 0;
        var end = GetEnd(@string, start);
        while (true)
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(
                @string.AsSpan(start, end - start),
                NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign,
                culture,
                out var number))
                throw new FormatException($"{GetType().Name} cannot parse string with invalid format.");
            numbers.Add(number);

            if (end == @string.Length)
                break;

            start = end + 1;
            end = GetEnd(@string, start);
        }
        return numbers;
    }

    private static int GetEnd(string @string, int start)
    {
        var end = @string.IndexOf(Separator, start);
        return end >= 0 ? end : @string.Length;
    }
}
```

The parsing uses `System.Memory` to avoid allocating a new string for each number in the list. If your framework doesn't have the `int.TryParse` overload that accepts a `Span<char>` you can use `string.Substring` instead.

Comment: This is should be accepted answer ❤  

You also can make the type converter generic: just use `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T))` instead of `int.TryParse(...)`